# Difference between C.I. and S.I. as percentage of Principal

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find difference between C.I. and S.I. Whalen Rate of interest and time are given but not Principal(Answer should be a percentage of Principal)?
Rate = 10% per annum
Time = 4 years
I know that it is (R/100)^2 for 2 years and ((R/100)^2)*(R/100+3) for three years.
Please help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because you are asked to express it as a percentage of principal, the actual principal amount doesn't matter.  Doubling the principal will double each of the interest amounts, doubling the difference, and leaving the percentage the same.  If you want to have a specific principal amount, just pick one.  It will divide out.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the interest rate is calculated once every year. Then:

C.I. (incl. principal): $ P \times (1+R)^t $

S.I. (incl. principal): $ P \times (1+Rt) $

where $P$ is the principal, $R$ is the interest rate and $t$ is the no. of years.

Difference in percentage of principal is:

$= \frac{P \times (1+R)^t - P \times (1+Rt)}{P} \times 100\% $

$= ((1+R)^t - (1+Rt)) \times 100\% $

**More generally**, if the interest rate is calculated $n$ times a year (e.g. if the interest is to be calculated once a month, then $n$ = $12$), then:

C.I. (incl. principal): $ P \times (1+\frac{R}{n})^{tn} $

S.I. (incl. principal): $ P \times (1+Rt) $

Difference in percentage of principal is:

$= \frac{P \times (1+\frac{R}{n})^{tn} - P \times (1+Rt)}{P} \times 100\% $

$= ((1+\frac{R}{n})^{tn} - (1+Rt)) \times 100\% $